# Python websockets onclose

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

In javascript, we have `WebSocket.onclose()` for doing some stuff when a websocket connection is closed by the server. Is there a way to do the same in a Python server when the connection is closed by the client device? The server is run using the `websockets` module itself using the `websockets.serve()` method. Both the `.Connected` & `.ConnectionClosed` aren't attributes of `WebSocketServerProtocol` (or so the error says). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both recv() and send() will raise a websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed on a closed connection.  Handle your cleanup there.  See https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/cheatsheet.html

Here's a slight modification of the websocket web example from the docs:

```
import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import websockets

async def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"
        try:
            await websocket.send(now)
        except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
            print("Client disconnected.  Do cleanup")
            break             
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)

start_server = websockets.serve(time, "127.0.0.1", 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Example client:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:5678"
    count = 5
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while count > 0:
            greeting = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"< {greeting}")
            count = count - 1

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

Comment: Thanks @clockwatcher. The `websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed` was all that I wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

To monitor closed websocket client connections from the server:

```
async def browser_server(websocket, path):
    closed = asyncio.ensure_future(websocket.wait_closed())
    closed.add_done_callback(lambda task: your_on_close_action())
```

https://github.com/python-websockets/websockets/issues/243